# Heroku Build Errors with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, knex.js, heroku-postgres

Hi thank you all in advance.

Can someone please explain to me how to approach this error.

I'm attempting to build my backend of a web application through Heroku and I keep getting the same errors. I have exhausted all options when attempting to figure out my issue.

I'm using Node.js with Knex for querying.
Have npm version 6.14.11 & node version v12.12.0

Here are some of my attempts:

1. I've deleted the node modules/package-lock.json & npm install again
2. Installed sqlite3@4.2.0 and node-pre-gyp
3. Moved dotenv as a devDepency.

I've provided code for the following:

1. Heroku Error
2. Package.json
3. Knex File
4. Server

Please let me know if more information is needed.
Here is the error I'm getting in Heroku:

```
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules
       
       > sqlite3@4.2.0 install /tmp/build_2aff7876_/node_modules/sqlite3
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
       
       internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
         throw err;
         ^
       
       Error: Cannot find module './internal/streams/buffer_list'
       Require stack:
       - /tmp/build_2aff7876_/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js
       - /tmp/build_2aff7876_/node_modules/readable-stream/readable.js
       - /tmp/build_2aff7876_/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/tracker-stream.js
       - /tmp/build_2aff7876_/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/tracker-group.js
       - /tmp/build_2aff7876_/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/index.js
       - /tmp/build_2aff7876_/node_modules/npmlog/log.js
       - /tmp/build_2aff7876_/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
       - /tmp/build_2aff7876_/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp
           at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
           at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
           at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
           at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
           at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_2aff7876_/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:72:18)
           at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
           at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
           at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
           at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
           at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19) {
         code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
         requireStack: [
           '/tmp/build_2aff7876_/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js',
           '/tmp/build_2aff7876_/node_modules/readable-stream/readable.js',
           '/tmp/build_2aff7876_/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/tracker-stream.js',
           '/tmp/build_2aff7876_/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/tracker-group.js',
           '/tmp/build_2aff7876_/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/index.js',
           '/tmp/build_2aff7876_/node_modules/npmlog/log.js',
           '/tmp/build_2aff7876_/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js',
           '/tmp/build_2aff7876_/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp'
         ]
       }
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 1
       npm ERR! sqlite3@4.2.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
       npm ERR! Exit status 1
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.2.0 install script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.E6bjK/_logs/2021-01-28T15_45_17_221Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Reficio_BE",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Backend For Reficio Database",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "cross-env DB_ENV=test jest --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "gitignore": "^0.6.0",
    "helmet": "^4.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "knex": "^0.21.5",
    "knex-cleaner": "^1.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.17.0",
    "pg": "^8.3.3",
    "sqlite3": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/hillan1152/Reficio_BE.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/hillan1152/Reficio_BE/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/hillan1152/Reficio_BE#readme"
}
```

Here is my Knex file:

```
// Update with your config settings.

module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: 'sqlite3',
    useNullAsDefault: true,
    connection: {
      filename: './data/database.db3'
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: './data/migrations'
    },
    seeds: {
      directory:'./data/seeds'
    },
    pool: {
      afterCreate: (conn, done) => {
                // runs after a connection is made to the sqlite engine
                conn.run('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON', done); // turn on FK enforcement
            }
    }
  },
  testing: {
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
      filename: './data/test.db3',
    },
    useNullAsDefault: true,
    pool: {
      afterCreate: (conn, done) => {
        conn.run("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON", done);
      },
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: './data/migrations',
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: './data/seeds',
    },
  },
  production: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    migrations: {
      directory: './data/migrations'
    },
    seeds: {
      directory:'./data/seeds'
    },
  },
};
```

Here is my server.js:

```
// IMPORT DEPENDENCIES
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require('helmet');

// IMPORT ROUTERS
const bookRouter = require('./routers/Book/book_router');
const chapterRouter = require('./routers/chapter/chapter_router');
const jobRouter = require('./routers/Jobs/job_router');
const codeRouter = require('./routers/Code/code_router');
const sectionRouter = require('./routers/Code/section_router');
const jobCodes = require('./routers/Jobs_codes/job_codes_router');
// SETTING UP SERVER
const server = express();
server.use(helmet());
server.use(cors());
server.use(express.json());

// a
// RUN SERVERS
server.use('/api/jobs', jobRouter);
server.use('/api/books', bookRouter);
server.use('/api/chapters', chapterRouter);
server.use('/api/codes', codeRouter);
server.use('/api/sections', sectionRouter);
server.use('/api/jobCodes', jobCodes);

// SET UP BASIC ENDPOINTS
server.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json('Server is running!')
});

module.exports = server;
```

Comment: tip #1. in dev env , rm -rf *  from node_modules then  "npm install" followed by "build" followed by "heroku local"  .. if that all works then git push to heroku should also work

Comment: tip #2 . Heroku set env may be used in the heroku dashboard for production env settings that you have in dev using a file ( .env )   . in this case  (dot)gitignore would contain entry for ".env" so as not to push.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're using `node-pre-gyp` for, but it doesn't seem like it's configured correctly. You need to add an `install` key to your `"scripts"` object in your `package.json`, as well as a `"binary"` key.

From the docs:

```js
"dependencies"  : {
      "node-pre-gyp": "0.6.x"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "aws-sdk": "2.x"
    }
    "scripts": {
        "install": "node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build"
    },
    "binary": {
        "module_name": "your_module",
        "module_path": "./lib/binding/",
        "host": "https://your_module.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
    }
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pre-gyp

Maybe that might help get you moving towards the right direction?